# JQuery live, bind not working for 'change'

Tags: bind, jquery

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that interacts with the Pandora player.  I need to know when the song changes.  I've identified which class (with a unique element) song data is written to, but I can't bind a JQuery 'change' handler to it.  In the following code, clicking on the element in question causes the correct alert to display, but no alert is displayed when the value of the element changes (when the song changes).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.playerBarSong').bind('click', function(){ alert("Click!"); });
$('.playerBarSong').bind('change', function(){ alert("Change!"); });
});
```

Furthermore, replacing  `bind` with `live` does not change the situation. How can I detect when the value of the element changes?

Comment: try `$(document).delegate(".playerBarSong", "change", function() {alert("Change!");});`

Comment: Trying now... Write this as an answer if you want me to Accept it if it works! :D

Comment: @rlemon That didn't work. Are you sure it isn't just doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try:

```
$('.playerBarSong').change(function(){alert("change!");});
```

Also what exactly is `playerBarSong`? Is it a value?